# crash application when scrolling map only when displaying annotaion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

My application is crashing when I scrolling map with displaying one or more annotation. Without display annotation map is working fine.

Now I can't understand what is problem here. Please Help Me.

Following is code that I used to display All annotation.

```
-(void)displayAllAnnotation
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[reminderTitle count]);
    for (int i=0 ; i<[reminderTitle count]; i++)
    {    
        double templati=[[reminderLatitude objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
        double templongi=[[reminderLongitude objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];


        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.latitude=(CLLocationDegrees)templati;
        coord.longitude=(CLLocationDegrees)templongi;
        DDAnnotation *ann = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord   addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];

        ann.title = [reminderTitle objectAtIndex:i];


        [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
        [ann release];

    }
}
```

Comment: put break point and see where your app crash?

Comment: and show us what is your crash log ?

Comment: when scrolling 4 to 5 times error is coming. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78456c0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You release *ann* object two times so your application is crashing.
remove *autorelease*. just write like this:

```
DDAnnotation *ann = [[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord   addressDictionary:nil];
```